# How to resolve issue with PHP5.6 error on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: mysql, php, 16.10

I have just upgraded to 16.10 from 16.04. I currently have PHP5.6 installed and have just tried to run a command in the terminal which is throwing the following error:

```
$ drush cc all
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY'
```

When I search online for how to resolve this I keep finding results that tell me to enable things like the php5-mysql extension. However I already have these extensions enabled.

Does anyone know how I can debug this and resolve it?

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed it. Though a bit counter intuitive I just had to install PHP7.0-mysql.

Comment: Use code formatting for command output, please. http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15152/158442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I am running PHP5.6 it turns out I still needed to install the PHP 7.0 mysql extension.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

Now it all seems to be working fine.